# Compare items in a SQL column with array

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arrays

I have a SQL server table where I want to query for items on rows which have a value equal to an item in Array. Here's my example:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
-------    -------    -------
aaa        100        200
bbb        100        400
aaa        200        78  
ccc        200        200
```

And my array:

```
string[] arr = {"ddd", "aaa", "fff", "bbb"}
```

So, I want to return from SQL rows matching items in the array. my SQL query should return items where column1 matches an item in the array:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
-------    -------    -------
aaa        100        200
bbb        100        400
aaa        200        78
```

This all in C# by the way. Help will be appreciate.

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ? Perfect for this sort of multisource comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build an SQL query with an `IN(@PARAM)` clause, and Join them with `String.Join`, like this:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        connectionString)) {
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE <FIELD> IN (@PARAM)";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"@PARAM",
                    String.Join(",", <array>)));
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader.HasRows) {
                // logic
            }
        } catch(SqlException) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The  items must be enclosed with ' ' (single quotes).

Comment: Great answer, I guess I was getting stuck on how to use a parameter to pass the values in the array back to SQL. Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `SQL` query you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 IN ('ddd', 'aaa', 'fff', 'bbb')
```

You can parse your array directly into the query.

Your post didn't mention anything about `LINQ`, which would make it even easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass these values as a `Table Value Parameter` to your `SP` and then `join` it to your table on Column1.

[Link: How to pass a TVP from C#](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/)