# comparing column in database to values in array of objects

Tags: php, codeigniter, filter, where-clause

i have this array of objects as a result of the following code:

```
$varIds = $this->user_model->get_var_id(...);
```

it produces something like this :

```
[
    {var_id: "141"}
    {var_id: "143"}
    {var_id: "146"}
    {var_id: "149"}
]
```

next step, sending this array to model like this:

```
$this->user_model->get_item_options_values_filter(...,$varIds);
```

next, filtering like this:

```
$this->db->where_in('items_options_value.var_id',$varIds);
```

i want to filter the rows based on the values in the $varIds array of objects, but this does not work as the where_in clause gives error **array to string conversion**, so how to compare the value of the var_id column with the values in $varIds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare items in a SQL column with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568528/compare-items-in-a-sql-column-with-array)

Comment: no, it uses different libraries, i search about them but it only shows results for c# and java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to first convert array of objects into array of values like this :

```
     $names = array();
     foreach($varIds as $v){
         array_push($names,$v['var_id']);
     }
```

then :

```
     $this->db->where_in('items_options_value.var_id',$names);
```